# Progressbar in concurrent request

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

I am making multiple concurrent requests on my server & it's working fine.

But I want to show the total progress of all request.

How can I achieve this?

**My Logic**

```
for i in 0..5 {

   POST Request1

   MultipartformData request2  

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `getTasksWithCompletionHandler`

Comment: @Lion, it shows me progress of per request only, not for multiple concurrent request.

Comment: @JonSnow, it shows me progress of per request only, not for multiple concurrent request.

Comment: @nirav according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1411578-gettaskswithcompletionhandler  It will return array of tasks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using libraries such as `Alamofire` or `AFNetworking` they provide you an `NSProgress` object.
The cool fact about `NSProgress`is that you can build a sort of hierarchy that keeps a global progress while you are adding child tasks.
For further information check these resources:

- [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress)
- [Tutorial by Ole Begeman](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/03/nsprogress/)
- [Tutorial by ToughBot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/asynchronous-nsprogress)